# Rails - Access Heroku DB from another rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two applications deployed in heroku which have their own pg database. I wonder is there a way so that one application can have the access to the db of other application without storing values in its own db.

Answer (score 0):

The database.yml looks like this:

```
production:
  primary:
    database: my_primary_database
    username: root
    password: <%= ENV['ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
    adapter: mysql2

  secondary:
    database: my_secondary_database
    username: secondary_root
    password: <%= ENV['SECONDARY_ROOT_PASSWORD'] %>
    adapter: mysql2
    migrations_paths: db/animals_migrate
```

Your model should have below:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

  connects_to database: { writing: :secondary }
end
```

Please have a look at the below documentation.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

I hope this will help you with what you want to achieve.

Comment: This might help me to get the data... thanks anyways